# Retrieving the index of a maximum value of an array

Tags: java, indexing, element

Say I have an array with elements {1,5,2,3,4}.
I have the code to find the maximum value, which is 5.
I would like to remove this value from the array by replacing array[1] with array[2], array[2] with  array[3], etc., and then making a new array with one less index (to not repeat the last value).
How can I find/state the index of the maximum value for an array, knowing what the maximum value is?
Would it be a lot different if we had an array where the maximum value occurs twice? {1,5,5,2,3}
Thank you very much.

EDIT1: I have figured out how to do it for one instance incorporating int maxIndex = 0; and setting it at the same time as the max value is set.
Now I just need to figure out for multiple instances.

```
int[] score = new int[5];
    for (int i=0 ; i<=4 ;i++)
{
    System.out.println("enter Score");

    score[i] = keyb.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(score)); //need import java.util.Arrays;

int max = score[0];
int maxIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1 ;  i<=score.length-1 ; i++)
{
    if (score[i] > max)
        {max = score[i];
    maxIndex= i; }
}
System.out.println("The maximum is " +max); //this finds the maximum. Now say we want to remove the maximum (no matter what the position)..
System.out.println("it is located at index " + maxIndex);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: If it would be different depends on your requirement and implementation, and finding the index should be the same as finding the maximum value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are not clear on your requirement: should we remove all occurrences of a max value or just a single occurrence?

Comment: Not even trying to use google?

Comment: Sorry I have not shown what I did. I didn't know where to start for the problem. I'm asking more of a general question BOND. If it is possible for a single occurrence, I may be able to figure out alone how to do all occurrences of the maximum value (if not so different).

Comment: This would be much easier using a `List` rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple instances, you can use a Set to keep track of the indices in the array that corresponds to the max number.

```
    int max = score[0];
    Set<Integer> maxIndices = new HashSet<>(); // a set that contains the indices of the max number in the array
    maxIndices.add(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= score.length - 1; i++) {
        if (score[i] > max) {
            max = score[i];
            maxIndices.clear(); // clear the set as we have a new max number
            maxIndices.add(i);
        } else if (score[i] == max) {
            maxIndices.add(i); // keep track of  all the indices in the array that corresponds to the max number
        }
    }

    // create the new array with the new size
    int newArrayWithoutMaxNums[] = new int[score.length - maxIndices.size()];
    int newCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; ++i) {
        if (!maxIndices.contains(i)) { // determine if the score is the max
            newArrayWithoutMaxNums[newCounter++] = score[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newArrayWithoutMaxNums.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print(newArrayWithoutMaxNums[i] + "\t");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public class findMaxIndex {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] score = new int[]{1,5,5,5,5,2,4,6,6,6,6,1,4,1};

int max = score[0];
int[] maxIndexArray = new int[score.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 1;  i <= score.length-1 ; i++) {
    if (score[i] > max) {
        max = score[i];
        j = 0;
        maxIndexArray = new int[score.length];
        maxIndexArray[j++] = i;
    }
    else if (score[i] == max) {
        maxIndexArray[j++] = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("The maximum is " +max); //this finds the maximum. Now say we want to remove the maximum (no matter what the position)..
System.out.println("it is located at index ");
 for (int i = 0; i < maxIndexArray.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(maxIndexArray[i]);
 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better things that you can do. However, I figure at least one simple example is good. Thus the below, though I certainly recommend trying to figure out the other answers as well even if the methods used are things you haven't learned yet.

Let's start by altering your code slightly.

```
int max = score[0];
int maxIndex[] = new int[score.length]
int maxCount = 0;
for (int i = 1 ;  i < score.length ; i++){
    if (score[i] > max){
        max = score[i];
        maxCount = 0;
        maxIndex[maxCount++] = i;
    }
    else if (score[i] == max)
    {
        //maxCount++ performs maxCount = maxCount+1; after the specified operation
        maxIndex[maxCount++] = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("The maximum is " + max);
System.out.print("This value occurs at: ");
for(int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++){
    System.out.print(maxIndex[i]);
}
```